# UI GameObject not visible in scene tab

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a networking game where a roomListItem shows all the available gamerooms online. for every gameroom a button gets instantiated inside the roomListItem and this happens as intended, the problem is that the button that gets instentiated is invisible, i can resize it but still can't see it.

i already tried moving the button at the bottom of the hierarchy but it's still not visible.

[image: Here is the image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are masking all the content, there is an object named `Viewport` that contains a mask component, this component causes that all UI elements below it will be masked, you can try:

1. Remove it.
2. Change the sprite for another one if you like to mask it in some way.

[image]

GIF here: https://share.getcloudapp.com/YEu8JPXN

Comment: Or a mask would do it. But yes, check the hierarchy.

Comment: The only "canvasGroups" are in the "container" gameObjects like "FindMatchContainer" and all of the canvas groups's alphas are set to 1.

Comment: That is too weird, if you like I can check it, can you share me your project? (Only the section that is broken). I need to see al components up and down in the hierechy.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1euE8w8QBRIIRbRS7rZ0Mw0eobpw3N_Bg?usp=sharing  Sorry if it took so many days to respond but i have never received a notifications of your response

Comment: To help you we need the project not the build xD

Comment: Oops sorry! that's right! https://github.com/Ardoriccardo00/Touhou99.git The scene is called Lobby.

Comment: Thank you for showing me the error! I made this Room list item by following a tutorial and i never thought about looking at the viewport object, i didn't even remember having a mask component!